# How can i change property value of specific directive reference from another directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have created directive where on click of button i change it's property value `status`.

```
{{ tempDirOne.status }}
<button appDirOne #tempDirOne="appDirOne">Diritive One first btn</button>

{{ tempDirTwo.status }}
<button appDirOne #tempDirTwo="appDirOne">Diritive One second btn</button>
```

**DIRECTIVE ONE**

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirOne]',
  exportAs: 'appDirOne'
})
export class DirOneDirective {
  status: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }

}
```

so i have two different references `tempDirOne` and `tempDirTwo`.

Now i have another directive where when it's element is clicked i need to change the `status` property of the first directive.

```
<button appDirTwo #tempDurSecondDirective="appDirTwo">Directive two button</button>
```

**THE SECOND DIRECTIVE**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirTwo]',
  exportAs: 'appDirTwo'
})
export class DirTwoDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    // change hier the status property of directive one - but
    // because there are two instances - change manually eiter on tempDirOne or tempDirTwo
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: You can create a separate service and inject it into both directives. Store the state into the service, https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services.

Comment: Otherwise you need an `@Output` EventEmiter to propagate the status change from the Dir2 to its parent, and have the parent propagate that change to the Dir1 via `@Input` parameter

Answer (score 2):

In angular you can get the reference of the another directive if both the directives on the `same element`.

But, in your case both the directives are in different elements and you `cannot` directly refer an instance of another directive.

To fulfil the requirement you could use `services` to update the status. In this approach you need to modify the component html to have another property `type` to differentiate between the two directive instances.

Below is the sample snippet for the same.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qbejij?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i  need somethign where i will choose from directive 2 which reference will i update. In your example it is just the first one

Comment: If you see the html snippet, I did add the new property type = "dir1". This is further referenced in ngOnInit of directive1 to check which directive value to be changed. you can add else part to update the instance 2 directive.

Comment: Your example does not work with two references. Emitting values will be set fthrough the service on all references. I devoted

Comment: As far as the stackblitz link I added in my answer, it is changing the status property of directive1 as it is subscribed for the service which is inline with what you asked in the question. Did you get a chance to play with the stackblitz? what you mean by "Emitting values will be set through the service on all references"?